# I want to show the limited amount of products using JCarousel module?

Tags: views, javascript

I am using [Jcarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module for products to show the front page. So I want to show the limited amount of products. I mentioned in views  **Use pager: Display a specified number of items | 5 items** .But it doesn't work it.. It shows the all produtcs in the front page.. How to configure it..

Comment: Are you sure you're setting it on the right display type, i.e., Page vs Block?  It's easy to change something in the wrong display.

Comment: I am sure . created as block only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the following code around line 147 of jcarousel.views.inc

```
if ($view->query->pager->options['items_per_page'] != 0){
    $count = min($view->query->pager->options['items_per_page'], $count);
}
```

You can read more about the issue at https://www.drupal.org/node/2408883